# マルチプラットフォーム上で動作するJavaScriptのランタイムエンジンはありますか？

Tags: javascript, c#

Windows, Mac, iOS, Android上で動作するアプリにJavaScriptのエンジンを組み込みたいです。

具体的には、Unityで作成しているアプリにJavaScriptファイルを動的に読み込み、実行できる機能を付けたいのですが良いライブラリ, SDKが見つかりません。

Googleの出しているV8エンジンを試してみたのですが、資料が乏しくて扱いづらいです。
c#に組み込むこと方法もわかりません。

満たしたい条件は以下の通りです。
・Windows, Mac, iOS, Androidで動作する。ビルドを分けて対応できるならそれでも良い。
・Unity、C#で扱うことが可能である。
・ECMA6以上に対応している。

今まで試したもの
・[Jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) (Unityで扱えるC#のバージョンで動作しない。ECMA5.1までしか正式対応してない)
・[ClearScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/ClearScript) (.NET Frameworkに依存していてWindowsでしか動作しない)
・<s>[ChakraCore](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore) (MicrosoftがEdgeでV8を使用することを発表するなど、将来性がないので使用を控えたい)</s>
追記(2018/12/15):Githubにある[このIssue](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/issues/5865)に寄ればこれからも更新され続けるらしい。
追記(2018/12/17):
・[BaristaCore](https://github.com/BaristaLabs/BaristaCore) (ChakraCoreを用いた.NET Standard準拠のライブラリ。)

追記(2019/1/2):上のBaristaCoreで開発をしてみることにしました。
ですが早速壁にぶち当たったので[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51661/baristacore%E3%81%8Cmac%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E5%8B%95%E4%BD%9C%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%8Cios%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%A7%E5%8B%95%E4%BD%9C%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E7%90%86%E7%94%B1%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93)で質問しております。

V8に関する情報でも別のエンジンに関する情報でもよいので教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 細かな対応状況までは確認できていませんが、GitHubにて"[javascript-engine](https://github.com/topics/javascript-engine)"とタグ付けされたリポジトリ一覧をチェックできますのでご参考に。

Comment: @cubick 貴重な情報ありがとうございます！早速リポジトリを一つ一つ確認していきます。

Comment: Unity自身がC#の他にJavaScriptを選択できたと思います。これを避けておきながらJavaScriptランタイムエンジンを探す意味がよくわかりません。

Comment: 最近のUnityはサポート言語がC#のみになっており、JavaScript(UnityScript)サポートは廃止されています。

Comment: 分かりにくい質問で申し訳ございません。
私がJavaScriptを書いて読み込ませたいわけではなく、後からユーザーの入力に応じて外部からJavaScriptが読み込まれ実行したいというわけです。
ブラウザのようなものを想像していただければ良いかと。

Comment: [こちらの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/51662/31396)によればそもそも無理な可能性が出てきてはおります。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

有効な回答がつかないので、現在わかっている情報を元に自分なりに結論付けたので自己回答しておきます。

他質問への回答に寄ればAppleのデベロッパーライセンス契約により、アプリに埋め込みでないスクリプトやインタープリタ機構を搭載することを禁じられていることがわかりました。

つまり少なくともiOSに関して言えば、私の期待しているJavaScriptエンジンを載せることは叶わないということです。

代わりに、iOSではJavaScriptCoreというエンジンを使うことができるので、こちらを用いて開発を進めていくことにしました。他プラットフォームに関してはV8を検討中です。

ありがとうございました。