# BaristaCoreがMac上では動作するがiOS上で動作しない理由がわかりません

Tags: javascript, unity3d

[こちらの質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51109/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AB%E3%83%81%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%A7%E5%8B%95%E4%BD%9C%E3%81%99%E3%82%8Bjavascript%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A0%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B8%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AF%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)をしたものです。
マルチプラットフォームで動作するJavaScriptのランタイムエンジンを探していて、皆さんのアドバイスもあって[BaristaCore](https://github.com/BaristaLabs/BaristaCore)というChakraCoreを使い.NET Standardで実装されたフレームワークを見つけたのですが、いざ開発してみるといきなり壁にぶち当たってしまいました。

MacとiOSで試すためにUnityを使ってテストを行いました。
[こちらのトピック](https://github.com/BaristaLabs/BaristaCore/wiki/Embedding-BaristaCore-into-your-own-application)を読みながらそのままで書いていたのですが、Macでは期待した動作をしてくれたのですがiOSにビルドしてみると上手く動作しませんでした。

そこで　Xcodeのログを読むと以下のようになっていました。

```
InvalidOperationException: 
A suitable constructor for type 'BaristaLabs.BaristaCore.BaristaRuntimeFactory' could not be located. 
Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.
```

エラー文で調べると`BaristaRuntimeFactory`のコンストラクタが`private`になっている可能性があると出たので早速[ソース](https://github.com/BaristaLabs/BaristaCore/blob/e0cee70a0e3de72411e636d72e63d4cc9a51202b/src/BaristaLabs.BaristaCore.Common/BaristaRuntimeFactory.cs)を読みましたが、コンストラクタは`public`になっていました。

これは私が何か前提を間違えているのか、BaristaCoreはiOSでは使えないのかが分かりません。
Unityのビルド設定でしなければいけないことがあるかも知れませんし、XcodeのLinked Frameworks and Librariesの欄に何か追加しなければいけないのかもしれません。

考えられる可能性は何でも教えていただきたいです。

かなり欲しい条件を満たしているので、できればこのままBaristaCoreを使いたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

逆にBaristaCoreがiOSで動作するという根拠が判りません。

該当ページの [README.md](https://github.com/BaristaLabs/BaristaCore) にも、そこで紹介されている  [Roadmap](https://github.com/BaristaLabs/BaristaCore/wiki/Roadmap) にも、macOSは記載されていますが、iOSはありません。

README.md

> Provides a sandboxed JavaScript runtime natively to a .Net Standard 2.0 application on Windows, Linux and macOS.

Roadmap

> Continuous Integration
> ☑ Automated Cross-Platform builds w/ Unit Tests
> ☑ Windows
> ☑ Linux
> ☑ macOS
> 　 Automated Releases
> 　 NuGet
> 　 Chocolatey
> 　 Apt-Get
> 　 Brew

ChakraCore自身もiOSで動かしたことはあるようですが、公式サポートはされていないようです。
[How can i build ChakraCore for IOS? #3179](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/issues/3179)

> There is no build configuration for iOS today. Some friends of the project have made it work on iOS, but there is not a PR or public fork at present.

ただし、誰もテストしていないだけで、動くのかもしれませんが、
その場合は誰か(貴方?)が動作確認やサポートのプロジェクトを立ち上げて
推進していく必要があるでしょう。

---

### 追記

古い記事なので今も当てはまるか不明ですが、こんな情報があります。何か参考になれば。
[Xamarin.Mac （か Xamarin.iOS ）から netstandard2 を使用する方法](https://qiita.com/toshi0607/items/8ff2b9ca54a0ad353f2f)
[Xamarin.Mac and netstandard2](https://medium.com/@donblas/xamarin-mac-and-netstandard2-708a06890302)
[Unable to build iOS project that references a NET Standard 2.0 library](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58504)

[Xamarin（Formsもね）で.NET Standard 2.0なライブラリを利用する](http://www.nuits.jp/entry/xamarin-forms-with-netstandard-20)
[.NET Standardなライブラリプロジェクトを作成して参照する](https://www.buildinsider.net/language/dotnetcore/05)

---

### さらに追記

こういう記事 [Is the `JS engine` on `IOS` or `MaxOS's` Chrome browser `V8`?Or `JavaScriptCode`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49890333/9014308) や [iOS版「Google Chrome」が速くない理由](http://ascii.jp/elem/000/000/707/707070/index-3.html) があって、技術的や個人使用では可能でも、商用・公開ソフトとしては作れないのかもしれませんね。

> AppleがiOSデベロッパーに課すライセンス契約（アプリ埋め込みでないスクリプト／インタープリタ機構の搭載を禁じる条項がある）により、...

Comment: 丁寧な回答ありがとうございます。
つまりアプリ内でJavaScriptを動的に外部からダウンロードしてきて実行するないし、なにがしかのインタープリタ機構を作ること自体が禁止されているという認識で間違いないでしょうか？

Comment: そうだと思います。類似の内容でAdobe FlashPlayerが許可されなかった件が有名だったはずです。